# Almost vector bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles

A reflexive sheaf (i.e its double dual is equal itself) is locally free (i.e., a holomorphic vector bundle) outside a subvariety of codimension greater than or equal to two. Let $\mathcal F$ be a coherent subsheaf of holomorphic vector bundle $E$, then there is an analytic subset $S \subset M$ of codimension bigger than two and a holomorphic vector bundle $F$ on $X \setminus S$ such that
$$\mathcal F|_{X\setminus S}=\mathcal O(F)$$

We know that a reflexive sheaf $\mathcal F$, on Kahler variety $X$ outside of codimension at least 3 is a holomorphic vector bundle,

> Under which condition such singular variety $S$ is an analytic sub-variety?

Comment: Always, right?  Coherence implies that one may locally write $\mathscr{F}$ as the cokernel of a map of trivial holomorphic vector bundles; $S$ is the locus where the rank of this map drops, so it's cut out by some matrix minors, which are analytic...

Comment: How did you know that statement about a reflexive sheaf being a vector bundle if it is .....?

Comment: Mohan, This is a theorem in the book of Kobayashi

Comment: The title of the question seems to be misleading. An "almost vector bundle" might be a vector bundle in the context of "almost mathematics". Besides that, the question is not even about the sheaf but about the variety S.

Comment: @HeleneSigloch ,ALMOST VECTOR BUNDLE in the following sense: If you take $Sing(\mathcal F) = \{x \in X | \mathcal F_x \text{is not free}\}$ where $\mathcal F_x$ is the stalk of $\mathcal F$ over $x$ ,  Then any torsion free sheaf  $\mathcal F$ out side of $Sing (\mathcal F)$ is vector bundle , since it is locally free. We say $\mathcal F$ is torsion free if $\mathcal F\to \mathcal F^{**}$ be injective and if it be isomorphism then it is called reflexive

Comment: @Hassan: Yes, I understood what you meant. Still, your question is about $S$, not about $\mathcal{F}$. Does this kind of sheaf run under the name of "almost vector bundle"? If this is not a commonly used name, then I think that the title of your question is misleading.

Comment: @HeleneSigloch , In the case when we want to consider the singularites of Yang-Mills solution, then analyticity of $S $ for compactness theorem is important. reflexive sheaf are singular extension of vector bundle and hence I think using Almost vector bundle is not too bad.

Comment: @Hassan, I just saw a source of confusion with Faltings' "almost mathematics", see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_ring - at least that's the reason why *I* clicked on your question. But never mind. It's not so important.